# Append to GNU 'make' variables via the command line

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am using a [GNU Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Derivatives) Makefile to build a C project with several targets (`all`, `clean`, and a few project specific targets). In the process of debugging, I would like to append some flags to a single build without permanently editing the Makefile (e.g., add debugging symbols or set a preprocessor flag).

In the past, I have done that as follows (using the debugging symbols example):

```
make target CFLAGS+=-g
```

Unfortunately, this is not appending to the `CFLAGS` variable, but instead, clearing it and stopping it from compiling. Is there a clean way of doing this without defining some sort of dummy variable appended to the end of `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Check out the [override directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive).  You will probably need to modify the makefile once, but it should do what you want.

Example makefile:

```
override CFLAGS += -Wall

app: main.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o app main.c
```

Example command lines:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -o app main.c 
$ make CFLAGS=-g
gcc -g -Wall -o app main.c
```

Answer (score 33):

For the record, [Carl Norum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129391/append-to-gnu-make-variables-via-command-line/2129409#2129409) *prepends* the variable, from the command line perspective.

I needed a way to actually append and came up with:

```
override CFLAGS := -Wall $(CFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 25):

There are two ways to pass variables to make:

- Using command line arguments:

  ```
  make VAR=value
  ```
- Using environment:

  ```
  export VAR=var; make
  ```

  or (better because it change environment only for current command)

  ```
  VAR=var make
  ```

They are slightly different. The first one is stronger. It mean you know what you want. The second may be considered like a hint. Difference between them is about operators `=` and `+=` (without `override`). These operators are ignored when a variable is defined on command line, but are not ignored when variable is defined in environment. Thus, I suggest you to have a Makefile with:

```
CC ?= gcc
CFLAGS += -Wall
INTERNAL_VARS = value
```

and call it with:

```
CFLAGS=-g make
```

Notice, if you want to withdraw `-Wall`, you can use:

```
make CFLAGS=
```

Please don't use `override` keyword, else you won't have any way to change a variable affected with `override`.

Answer (score 9):

Just a note, as I got confused - let this be file `testmake`:

```
$(eval $(info A: CFLAGS here is $(CFLAGS)))

override CFLAGS += -B

$(eval $(info B: CFLAGS here is $(CFLAGS)))

CFLAGS += -C

$(eval $(info C: CFLAGS here is $(CFLAGS)))

override CFLAGS += -D

$(eval $(info D: CFLAGS here is $(CFLAGS)))

CFLAGS += -E

$(eval $(info E: CFLAGS here is $(CFLAGS)))
```

Then:

```
$ make -f testmake
A: CFLAGS here is 
B: CFLAGS here is -B
C: CFLAGS here is -B
D: CFLAGS here is -B -D
E: CFLAGS here is -B -D
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
$ make -f testmake CFLAGS+=-g
A: CFLAGS here is -g
B: CFLAGS here is -g -B
C: CFLAGS here is -g -B
D: CFLAGS here is -g -B -D
E: CFLAGS here is -g -B -D
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

With the `override` directives deleted from the `testmake` file:

```
$ make -f testmake
A: CFLAGS here is 
B: CFLAGS here is -B
C: CFLAGS here is -B -C
D: CFLAGS here is -B -C -D
E: CFLAGS here is -B -C -D -E
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
$ make -f testmake CFLAGS+=-g
A: CFLAGS here is -g
B: CFLAGS here is -g
C: CFLAGS here is -g
D: CFLAGS here is -g
E: CFLAGS here is -g
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

So,

- if a variable used `override` once, it can only be appended with another statement with `override` (the normal assignments will be ignored);
- when there's been no `override` at all; trying to append (as in `+=`) from the command line overwrites every instance of that variable.

Comment: Excellent example!