# How to print the ld(linker) search path

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, ld

What is the way to print the search paths that in looked by **ld** in the order it searches.

Answer (score 166):

You can do this by executing the following command:

```
ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012
```

**gcc** passes a few extra -L paths to the linker, which you can list with the following command:

```
gcc -print-search-dirs | sed '/^lib/b 1;d;:1;s,/[^/.][^/]*/\.\./,/,;t 1;s,:[^=]*=,:;,;s,;,;  ,g' | tr \; \\012
```

The answers suggesting to use ld.so.conf and ldconfig are not correct because they refer to the paths searched by the runtime dynamic linker (i.e. whenever a program is executed), which is not the same as the path searched by **ld** (i.e. whenever a program is linked).

Comment: You hit the spot. I have a linking problem, during linking process linker finds manually installed libraries in `/usr/local/..` which causes missing library error, and linking fails. I have to rename `/usr/local` everytime to exclude that search path. Is there a simple way to exclude or override `/usr/local` path?

Comment: You can try to manually specify library paths with the -L option to GCC, which I think (not sure) will override the system library paths. You could also try to set the LIBRARY_PATH env variable before compiling: $ LIBRARY_PATH=/somedir/ gcc ...

Comment: I know that linking in command line compiling. I meant a global way to override `ld`s search path. For example sometimes I have to compile a source code from `makefile` or generating makefile from `configure` script or from `CMakeLists.txt` or even more complicated ones such as `vala` or `srt`. It's hard for me to modify `ld` search path in such cases

Comment: When using CMake you can select the exact libraries which are used during the configuration phase (some of these entries are shown only in advanced mode). As for configure scripts from Autotools, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561509/how-to-add-include-and-lib-paths-to-configure-make-cycle. This doesn't answer your question directly, but may help you do what you want.

Comment: Ah, now this explains why building with local libraries is so broken in Centos. Includes path searches are `/usr/local/include` then `/usr/include`, while linker search is `/usr/lib64` then `/usr/local/lib64`

Comment: Why if I add option `-Lpath` to gcc I can´t see changes in output of `gcc -print-search-dirs`?

Answer (score 92):

On Linux, you can use `ldconfig`, which maintains the ld.so configuration and cache, to print out the directories search by `ld.so` with

```
ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
```

`ldconfig -v` prints out the directories search by the linker (without a leading tab) and the shared libraries found in those directories (with a leading tab); the `grep` gets the directories. On my machine, this line prints out

```
/usr/lib64/atlas:
/usr/lib/llvm:
/usr/lib64/llvm:
/usr/lib64/mysql:
/usr/lib64/nvidia:
/usr/lib64/tracker-0.12:
/usr/lib/wine:
/usr/lib64/wine:
/usr/lib64/xulrunner-2:
/lib:
/lib64:
/usr/lib:
/usr/lib64:
/usr/lib64/nvidia/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
/lib/i686: (hwcap: 0x0008000000000000)
/lib64/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
/usr/lib/sse2: (hwcap: 0x0000000004000000)
/usr/lib64/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)
/usr/lib64/sse2: (hwcap: 0x0000000004000000)
```

The first paths, without `hwcap` in the line, are either built-in or read from /etc/ld.so.conf.
The linker can then search additional directories under the basic library search path, with names like `sse2` corresponding to additional CPU capabilities.
These paths, with `hwcap` in the line, can contain additional libraries tailored for these  CPU capabilities.

One final note: using `-p` instead of `-v` above searches the `ld.so` cache instead.

Comment: He is asking about the linker (ld) and not the loader (ld.so)!

Comment: How is it possible that if I set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/other/dir`, it will not affect output of this command?! Seems it doesn't work 100%?

Comment: @fons Funnything is that I got here looking for this answer. :) link-time or run-time path? I guess that's the question. LIBRAY_PATH (link time) vs LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I've found on some platforms (e.g. arm with Linaro toolchain) that ldconfig doesn't actually search the same directories as the run time linker. You *can* get it to output its search path, and include the paths from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by enabling debugging. E.g. `LD_DEBUG=libs /lib/ld-linux.so --list cat` (you can use any executable, I picked `cat` as the first thing I could think of). Might be worth grepping for "`search path`". Note that if you have an `/etc/ld.so.cache` that matches all needed libs, you won't get to see the built-in system search path, because it won't get that far.

Comment: Is `gcc` search path the same with these?

Comment: Be careful with `ldconfig -v` on FreeBSD, it will permanently remove all configured directories. Use `ldconfig -r` instead on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 76):

I'm not sure that there is any option for simply printing the full effective search path.

But: the search path consists of directories specified by `-L` options on the command line, followed by directories added to the search path by `SEARCH_DIR("...")` directives in the linker script(s).  So you can work it out if you can see both of those, which you can do as follows:

If you're invoking `ld` directly:

- The `-L` options are whatever you've said they are.
- To see the linker script, add the `--verbose` option.  Look for the `SEARCH_DIR("...")` directives, usually near the top of the output.  (Note that these are not necessarily the same for every invocation of `ld` -- the linker has a number of different built-in default linker scripts, and chooses between them based on various other linker options.)

If you're linking via `gcc`:

- You can pass the `-v` option to `gcc` so that it shows you how it invokes the linker.  In fact, it normally does not invoke `ld` directly, but indirectly via a tool called `collect2` (which lives in one of its internal directories), which in turn invokes `ld`.  That will show you what `-L` options are being used.
- You can add `-Wl,--verbose` to the `gcc` options to make it pass `--verbose` through to the linker, to see the linker script as described above.

Comment: The --verbose option for the linker did the trick. Very helpful!

Comment: I was trying hard to figure out where the linker was looking and did not find SEARCH_DIR in the output. Turns out as I was using `-T script` my script completely replaced ld's default script and only looked where I pointed.

Answer (score 35):

The most compatible command I've found for gcc and clang on Linux (thanks to armando.sano):

```
$ gcc -m64 -Xlinker --verbose  2>/dev/null | grep SEARCH | sed 's/SEARCH_DIR("=\?\([^"]\+\)"); */\1\n/g'  | grep -vE '^$'
```

if you give `-m32`, it will output the correct library directories.

Examples on my machine:

for `g++ -m64`:

```
/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64
/usr/i686-linux-gnu/lib64
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/local/lib64
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib64
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib64
/usr/local/lib
/lib
/usr/lib
```

for `g++ -m32`:

```
/usr/i686-linux-gnu/lib32
/usr/local/lib32
/lib32
/usr/lib32
/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/local/lib
/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/lib
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib
```

Comment: Thank you!  teeny enhancement -- get rid of a grep or two:  sed -n 's/SEARCH_DIR("=\?\([^"]\+\)"); */\1\n/gp'

Comment: Why does this require such an obscure method?

Comment: This worked like a charm ! how do we add the directories on this list , linker search path ?

Answer (score 6):

The question is tagged Linux, but maybe this works as well under Linux?

```
gcc -Xlinker -v
```

Under Mac OS X, this prints:

```
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-224.1
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
[...]
```

The `-Xlinker` option of `gcc` above just passes `-v` to `ld`. However:

```
ld -v
```

doesn't print the search path.

Comment: On Linux it prints directories as well, but in form of `-Lpath`. So @Raphaël Londeix answer is better.

Answer (score 3):

Mac version: $ ld -v 2, don't know how to get detailed paths.
output

```
Library search paths:
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
```

Comment: I get "cannot open 2: no such file or directory".  Running `ld -v 2`

Comment: The question is tagged Linux, not OS X. I don't believe OS X uses GNU's `ld`. The Binutil folks disabled it in the build scripts. It has been disabled for years.