# Without admin prevlieges, how do I find the directories searched by ld?

Tags: linux, gcc, static-libraries, gnu, ld

How do I find the directories searched in by the [GNU linker](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld), without admin privileges?

---

I can get the listing in the following way:

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/fglrx:
/usr/lib32/fglrx:
/lib32:
/usr/lib32:
/lib:
/usr/lib:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2: (hwcap: 0x0000000004000000)
```

this solution came from:  [How to print the ld(linker) search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922949/how-to-print-the-ldlinker-search-path)

---

However, on a machine where I do not have admin privileges, this will not work.  I assume that’s because ldconfig is located in /sbin/.  I download [glibc](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/) and installed it locally to create another version of ldconfig.  I guess that was silly though because the local version gives me:

```
/usr/local/lib:
/usr/local/lib64:
```

Is it still possible to get all the directories as a non-admin?
There doesn't appear to be any helpful ld flags, or environment variables to do the job.

Comment: This question would be better at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) or [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because `ldconfig` is in `sbin` doesn't mean it can't be run as a normal user. Simply use that command and specify the full path to `ldconfig`:

```
/sbin/ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
```