# gm convert: FreeType library is not available (/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/n019003l.pfb)

Tags: freetype

It's on OS X 10.9. I installed GraphicsMagick with `brew`, and FreeType v2.5.2. But when I use gm convert in my program, I got this error:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: gm convert: FreeType library is not available (/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/n019003l.pfb).
] code: 1, signal: null }
```

My FreeType:

```
flyn:Font ijse$ freetype-config --libs
-L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.2/lib -lfreetype -lz -lbz2 -lpng15
```

I've been searched on google for a while but got no answer.

Comment: facing same problem. have u found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to investigate a bit more:

1) Which binary is producing that error? Say it's `gm`. Please post output of

```
ldd `which gm`
```

to see if the library is linked directly.

2) if yes, try to add your path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. Look if your path is there (here is how to do it: [How to print the ld(linker) search path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922949))

3) if no, have look in the configuration files

**EDIT:**  Run `freetype-config --libs`. The path behind `-L` is **the real location of the library**. Is it anywhere in the output of the following command?

```
ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
```

This command shows [where the libraries are looked for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922949). Is the location of your freetype library there? If yes, it is OK. If no, this is the cause of your problem! Try one of these:

- make symlinks from one of those directories to your library
- set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/location/of/your/freetype/libraries` in the script that run the program that issues the above error.

Comment: Hi good day, care to share more details regarding the configuration files ?

Comment: @DjangoRocks unfortunatelly I don't have the software, cannot look, but I will try to help. is the file `/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/n019003l.pfb` on your system or not?

Comment: @DjangoRocks OK. please follow the update in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW I ran into this same issue on my Mac and solved it as follows:

- `brew uninstall graphicsmagick imagemagick`
- Ensure that `freetype` was installed (`brew info freetype`)
- `brew install imagemagick`
- `magick -version` to ensure you see freetype listed there
- Edit the `graphicsmagick` formula via `brew edit graphicsmagick` to add the `--with-freetype` flag to the build flags
- Run `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install graphicsmagick`
- Run `gm -version` and ensure it says "FreeType Yes"
- Try your script again