# Cannot find sdl2main

Tags: c++, graphics, g++

I'm trying to compile code using SDL, I can't really post much of the code here but I can do my best to answer questions about it. The problem occurs when compiling the view code and trying to link the SDL libraries.

```
g++ -o test test.c -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

gives me an error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2main`

I know my SDL install is okay because if I leave out the link to SDL2main it compiles fine and runs fine. The problem is there is other code that needs SDL2main. I've poured through my file system and I can't find it and I've searched online pretty exhaustively. I was just hoping someone could help me either resolve the dependency or fix my sdl install if its broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using some distro there's probably some tool to search files, even in packages not installed.

For example (I'm using Debian/unstable) `apt-file search SDL2main`

`libsdl2-dev: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSDL2main.a`

```
libsdl2-2.0-0:i386       2.0.2+dfsg1-4            
libsdl2-dev              2.0.2+dfsg1-4
```

Once you've verified that the lib exist if it doesn't link there still something to check and try

Check the lib is installed in one of the *search path* (see [How to print the ld(linker) search path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922949/2498790))

Or explicit the path

`g++ -o test test.c -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lSDL2main -lSDL2`

Being a static library with some `gcc/g++/ld` version maybe you need to link the archive as an object, without `-l`

`g++ -o test test.c /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSDL2main.a -lSDL2`