# cpp: usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>

Tags: c++

I created a cpp project, which used a lib file named: `libblpapi3_64.so`
This file comes from a library which I download it from Internet.

My project runs without any error. So I update it to bitbucket.
Then my colleague downloads it and runs it at his own computer. But he gets an error:

`usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblpapi3_64`.

In fact, I have copied it into my project repository. I mean I created a file named lib under my project and all lib files that I used are in it.

There are also other lib files such as `liblog4cpp.a`, but they are all good. Only the `libblpapi3_64.so` gets the error.

Is it because it's a .so file not `.a` file? Or there is other reason?
Btw, the file name of `libblpapi3_64.so` is `green` and others files(.a) is `white`. I think it's not a link file, it's the original file.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Briefly:**

`ld` does not know about where your project libs are located. You have to place it into ld's known directories or specify the full path of your library by `-L` parameter to the linker.

To be able to build your program you need to have your library in `/bin/ld` search paths and your colleague too. Why? See detailed answer.

**Detailed:**

At first, we should understand what tools do what:

1. The compiler produces simple `object files` with unresolved symbols (it does not care about symbols so much at it's running time).
2. The linker combines a number of `object` and `archive files`, relocates their data and ties up symbol references into a single file: an executable or a library.

Let's start with some example. For example, you have a project which consists of 3 files: `main.c`, `func.h` and `func.c`.

**main.c**

```
#include "func.h"
int main() {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

**func.h**

```
void func();
```

**func.c**

```
#include "func.h"
void func() { }
```

So, when you compile your source code (`main.c`) into an object file (`main.o`) it can't be run yet because it has unresolved symbols. Let's start from the beginning of `producing an executable` workflow (without details):

The preprocessor after its job produces the following `main.c.preprocessed`:

```
void func();
int main() {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

and the following `func.c.preprocessed`:

```
void func();
void func() { }
```

As you may see in `main.c.preprocessed`, there are no connections to your `func.c` file and to the `void func()`'s implementation, the compiler simply does not know about it, it compiles all the source files separately. So, to be able to compile this project you have to compile both source files by using something like `cc -c main.c -o main.o` and `cc -c func.c -o func.o`, this will produce 2 object files, `main.o` and `func.o`. `func.o` has all it's symbols resolved because it has only one function which body is written right inside the `func.c` but `main.o` does not have `func` symbol resolved yet because it does not know where it is implemented.

Let's look what is inside `func.o`:

```
$ nm func.o
0000000000000000 T func
```

Simply, it contains a symbol which is in text code section so this is our `func` function.

And let's look inside `main.o`:

```
$ nm main.o
                 U func
0000000000000000 T main
```

Our `main.o` has an implemented and resolved static function `main` and we are able to see it in the object file. But we also see `func` symbol which marked as unresolved `U`, and thus we are unable to see its address offset.

For fixing that problem, we have to use the linker. It will take all the object files and resolve all these symbols (`void func();` in our example). If the linker somehow is unable to do that it throws a error like `unresolved external symbol`: `void func()`. This may happen if you don't give the `func.o` object file to the linker. So, let's give all the object files we have to the linker:

```
ld main.o func.o -o test
```

The linker will go through `main.o`, then through `func.o`, try to resolve symbols and if it goes okay - put it's output to the `test` file. If we look at the produced output we will see all symbols are resolved:

```
$ nm test 
0000000000601000 R __bss_start
0000000000601000 R _edata
0000000000601000 R _end
00000000004000b0 T func
00000000004000b7 T main
```

Here our job is done. Let's look the situation with dynamic(shared) libraries. Let's make a shared library from our `func.c` source file:

```
gcc -c func.c -o func.o
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libfunc.so.1 -o libfunc.so.1.5.0 func.o
```

Voila, we have it. Now, let's put it into known dynamic linker library path, `/usr/lib/`:

```
sudo mv libfunc.so.1.5.0 /usr/lib/ # to make program be able to run
sudo ln -s libfunc.so.1.5.0 /usr/lib/libfunc.so.1  #creating symlink for the program to run
sudo ln -s libfunc.so.1 /usr/lib/libfunc.so # to make compilation possible
```

And let's make our project depend on that shared library by leaving `func()` symbol unresolved after compilation and static linkage process, creating an executable and linking it (dynamically) to our shared library (`libfunc`):

```
cc main.c -lfunc
```

Now if we look for the symbol in its symbols table we still have our symbol unresolved:

```
$ nm a.out | grep fun
             U func
```

But this is not a problem anymore because `func` symbol will be resolved by dynamic loader before each program start. Okay, now let's back to the theory.

Libraries, in fact, are just the object files which are placed into a single archive by using `ar` tool with a single symbols table which is created by `ranlib` tool.

Compiler, when compiling object files, does not resolve `symbols`. These symbols will be replaced to addresses by a linker. So resolving symbols can be done by two things: `the linker` and `dynamic loader`:

1. The linker: `ld`, does 2 jobs:

   a) For static libs or simple object files, this linker changes external symbols in the object files to the addresses of the real entities. For example, if we use C++ name mangling linker will change `_ZNK3MapI10StringName3RefI8GDScriptE10ComparatorIS0_E16DefaultAllocatorE3hasERKS0_` to `0x07f4123f0`.

   b) For dynamic libs it only **checks** if the symbols **can be resolved** (you try to link with correct library) at all but does not replace the symbols by address. If symbols can't be resolved (for example they are not implemented in the shared library you are linking to) - it throws `undefined reference to` error and breaks up the building process because you try to use these symbols but linker can't find such symbol in it's object files which it is processing at this time. Otherwise, this linker adds some information to the `ELF` executable which is:

   i. `.interp` section - request for an `interpreter` - dynamic loader to be called before executing, so this section just contains a path to the dynamic loader. If you look at your executable which depends on shared library (`libfunc`) for example you will see the interp section `$ readelf -l a.out`:

   ```
   INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                  0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
   [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
   ```

   ii. `.dynamic` section - a list of shared libraries which `interpreter` will be looking for before executing. You may see them by `ldd` or `readelf`:

   ```
   $ ldd a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd577dc000)
        libfunc.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfunc.so.1 (0x00007fc629eca000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fefe148a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055747925e000)

   $ readelf -d a.out

     Dynamic section at offset 0xe18 contains 25 entries:
     Tag        Type                         Name/Value
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libfunc.so.1]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
   ```

   Note that `ldd` also finds all the libraries in your filesystem while readelf only shows what libraries does your program need. So, all of these libraries will be searched by dynamic loader (next paragraph).
   The linker works at **build time**.
2. Dynamic loader: `ld.so` or `ld-linux`. It finds and loads all the shared libraries needed by a program (if they were not loaded before), resolves the symbols by replacing them to real addresses right before the start of the program, prepares the program to run, and then runs it. It works **after the build and before running the program**. Less speaking, dynamic linking means resolving symbols in your executable before each program start.

Actually, when you run an `ELF` executable with `.interp` section (it needs to load some shared libraries) the OS (Linux) runs an interpreter at first but not your program. Otherwise you have an undefined behavior - you have symbols in your program but they are not defined by addresses which usually means that the program will be unable to work properly.

You may also run dynamic loader by yourself but it is unnecessary (binary is `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` for 32-bit architecture elf and `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` for 64-bit architecture elf).

Why does the linker claim that `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblpapi3_64` in your case? Because it tries to find all the libraries in it's known paths. Why does it search the library if it will be loaded during runtime? Because it needs to check if all the needed symbols can be resolved by this library and to put it's name into the `.dynamic` section for dynamic loader. Actually, the `.interp` section exists in almost every c/c++ elf because the `libc` and `libstdc++` libraries are both shared, and compiler by default links any project dynamically to them. You may link them statically as well but this will enlarge the total executable size. So, if the shared library can't be found your symbols will remain unresolved and you will be **UNABLE** to run your application, thus it can't produce an executable. You may get the list of directories where libraries are usually searched by:

1. Passing a command to the linker in compiler arguments.
2. By parsing `ld --verbose`'s output.
3. By parsing `ldconfig`'s output.

Some of these methods are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922949/how-to-print-the-ldlinker-search-path).

**Dynamic loader** tries to find all the libraries by using:

1. `DT_RPATH` dynamic section of an ELF file.
2. `DT_RUNPATH` section of the executable.
3. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.
4. `/etc/ld.so.cache` - own cache file which contains a compiled list of candidate libraries previously found in the augmented library path.
5. Default paths: In the default path /lib, and then /usr/lib. If the binary was linked with `-z nodeflib` linker option, this step is skipped.

[ld-linux search algorithm](https://grahamwideman.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/the-linux-loader-and-how-it-finds-libraries/)

Also, note please, that if we are talking about shared libraries, they are not named `.so` but in `.so.version` format instead. When you build your application the linker will look for `.so` file (which is usually a symlink to `.so.version`) but when you run your application the dynamic loader looks for `.so.version` file instead. For example, let's say we have a library `test` which version is `1.1.1` according to [semver](http://semver.org/). In the filesystem it will look like:

```
/usr/lib/libtest.so -> /usr/lib/libtest.so.1.1.1
/usr/lib/libtest.so.1 -> /usr/lib/libtest.so.1.1.1
/usr/lib/libtest.so.1.1 -> /usr/lib/libtest.so.1.1.1
/usr/lib/libtest.so.1.1.1
```

So, to be able to compile you must have all of versioned files (`libtest.so.1`, `libtest.so.1.1` and `libtest.so.1.1.1`) and a `libtest.so` file but for running your app you must have only 3 versioned library files listed first. This also explains why do Debian or rpm packages have `devel`-packages separately: normal one (which consists only of the files needed by already compiled applications for running them) which has 3 versioned library files and a devel package which has only symlink file for making it possible to compile the project.

**Resume**

After all of that:

1. You, your colleague and **EACH** user of your application code must have all the libraries in their system linker paths to be able to compile (build your application). Otherwise, they have to change Makefile (or compile command) to add the shared library location directory by adding `-L<somePathToTheSharedLibrary>` as argument.
2. After successful build you also need your library again to be able to run the program. Your library will be searched by dynamic loader (`ld-linux`) so it needs to be in **it's paths** (see above) or in system linker paths. In most of linux program distributions, for example, games from steam, there is a shell-script which sets the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable which points to all shared libraries needed by the game.

Comment: you mean -L (-I is for include paths)

Comment: thx a lot. In fact this is my first time that working under linux. What I am thinking is that my colleague download my project from bitbucket and then he could use it immediately. So when I code, I create a file and put all of lib files in it. My IDE is Netbeans, I click right on my project and I can add lib files in that file. After that, I update the whole project to bitbucket. When my colleague download it and import it into his Netbeans, I could see all lib files have been configured --- just like what I have done before. So you are telling me that what I have done doesn't work?

Comment: in other words, is it possible that my colleague can compile it immediately without any configuration?

Comment: It depends on have your colleague this library in his library paths. I'll modify the answer accordingly soon

Answer (score 0):

You could look at our [Rblapi](https://github.com/armstrtw/Rblpapi) package which uses this very library too.

Your basic question of "how do I make a library visible" really has two answers:

1. Use `ld.so`. The easiest way is to copy `blpapi3_64.so` to `/usr/local/lib`. If you then call `ldconfig` to update the cache you should be all set. You can test this via `ldconfig -p | grep blpapi` which should show it.
2. Use an `rpath` instruction when building your application; this basically encodes the path and makes you independent of `ld.so`.

Comment: thx a lot. In fact this is my first time that working under linux. What I am thinking is that my colleague download my project from bitbucket and then he could use it immediately. So when I code, I create a file and put all of lib files in it. My IDE is Netbeans, I click right on my project and I can add lib files in that file. After that, I update the whole project to bitbucket. When my colleague download it and import it into his Netbeans, I could see all lib files have been configured --- just like what I have done before. So you are telling me that what I have done doesn't work?

Comment: in other words, is it possible that my colleague can compile it immediately without any configuration?

Comment: Yes,  if you know what you are doing you can achieve that.  For example our Rblpapi package works *exactly* that way.