# docker build error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ fedora29

Tags: c++, docker

I'm trying to build a docker container using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:29

RUN dnf -y update && dnf install -y file gcc gcc-c++ git make wget which libtool python3-pip redhat-rpm-config python3-devel zlib-devel libstdc++ openmpi-devel

RUN cd /tmp && \
wget http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.3/mpich-3.3.tar.gz && \
gzip -dc mpich-3.3.tar.gz | tar xf - && \
cd mpich-3.3 && \
./configure --disable-fortran --prefix=/usr/mpich-3.3 && \
make && \
make install

ENV PATH            /usr/mpich-3.3/bin:${PATH}
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/mpich-3.3/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

RUN cd /usr && git clone https://github.com/Dowell-Lab/FStitch
RUN              cd /usr/FStitch/src && make clean && make
RUN pip3 install FStitch-Bidir --user
ENV PATH            /usr/FStitch/src:${PATH}
ENV PATH            /root/.local/bin:${PATH}

RUN cd /usr && git clone https://github.com/Dowell-Lab/Tfit
RUN              cd /usr/Tfit/src && make clean && make 
ENV PATH            /usr/Tfit/src:${PATH}

CMD /bin/bash
```

Where the projects I'm trying to clone are written in c++11 and the second of the two (Tfit) requires openmpi/mpich. The first program compiles successfully, but with the second, I'm getting the following error in the last step of the compiler:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:20: NU_FIT] Error 1
```

I searched and found these two links:

[cpp: usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600978/cpp-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

[usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

But neither of these quite address the problem as I'm guessing I'm just missing a dependency/symlink to a library, but I'm unsure how to achieve this in the build. I can compile this successfully locally, but I have to module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64 to do so. My guess is that this is an openmpi issue when setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but am unsure of how to resolve this in the Docker build.

The first few lines of the Makefile are as follows:

```
CXX             = mpic++
CXXFLAGS        = -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -fopenmp -Wno-write-strings -Wno-literal-suffix -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -g
EXEC            = ${PWD}/Tfit
ARCH                     = getconf LONG_BIT

CPP_FLAGS_32    = -D32_BIT
CPP_FLAGS_64    = -D64_BIT

GCCVERSION      = $(shell ${CXX} -dumpversion)
NU_FIT: main.o load.o split.o model.o across_segments.o template_matching.o \
    read_in_parameters.o model_selection.o error_stdo_logging.o \
    MPI_comm.o  density_profiler.o bootstrap.o prelim_main.o model_main.o select_main.o FDR.o BIC.o ParamWrapper.o old_template_matching.o
    @printf "linking               : "
    @${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS}  ${PWD}/main.o ${PWD}/load.o ${PWD}/model_selection.o \
    ${PWD}/split.o ${PWD}/model.o ${PWD}/across_segments.o  \
    ${PWD}/template_matching.o ${PWD}/read_in_parameters.o  \
    ${PWD}/MPI_comm.o   \
    ${PWD}/bootstrap.o ${PWD}/density_profiler.o \
    ${PWD}/prelim_main.o ${PWD}/model_main.o ${PWD}/BIC.o ${PWD}/FDR.o  \
    ${PWD}/select_main.o  ${PWD}/error_stdo_logging.o ${PWD}/ParamWrapper.o ${PWD}/old_template_matching.o -o ${EXEC} -lmpi
    @cp ${PWD}/Tfit ${PWD}/EMGU
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `libstdc++-static` in your list of `dnf install`. (https://github.com/numenta/nupic/issues/1901)