# A question about "libtensorflow_framework" in colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, compilation, google-colaboratory

I ran the following comments in colab cell to add libtensorflow_framework.so to the gcc's searching routine:

```
! echo '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/' >> /etc/ld.so.conf
! sudo ldconfig
! export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/
! echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/' >> ~/.bashrc
! source ~/.bashrc
```

and got (I do not know if it is this question's key point)

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ideep4py/lib/libmkldnn.so.0 is not a symbolic link
```

since in tensorflow 2.2.0-rc3 the " libtensorflow_framework.so " is modified to " libtensorflow_framework.so.2 ", so I created a soft connection between them:

```
!sudo ln -s libtensorflow_framework.so.2 libtensorflow_framework.so
```

but when I finally run the comments:

```
TF_INC=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())')
TF_LIB=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib())')
# TF1.4
g++ -std=c++11 tf_grouping.cpp tf_grouping_g.cu.o -o tf_grouping_so.so -shared -fPIC -I 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/include -I /usr/local/cuda/include -I 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/external/nsync/public -lcudart -L 
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -L/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow -llibtensorflow_framework -O2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -I$TF_INC/external/nsync/public -L$TF_LIB -llibtensorflow_framework
```

I still get the feedback:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibtensorflow_framework
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibtensorflow_framework
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/30601010/14290244