# CMake: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I use CMake 3.5.2. When trying to build my C++ code I get the following error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable SomeExecutable
CMakeFiles/SomeExecutable.dir/Common/src/FunctionOne.cpp.o: In function `FunctionOne::FunctionOne(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, double, unsigned int, bool)':
FunctionOne.cpp:(.text+0x490): undefined reference to `Helper::initLevel(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
```

The program doesn't find Helper::initLevel() in myLib.so. How do I fix it?

**CMakeLists.txt: (shortened for brevity)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(ProjectName)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)
add_definitions(-Wall)
add_definitions(-O2)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)    

add_executable(SomeExecutable SomeExecutable.cpp ${FunctionOne} ${FunctionTwo})
target_link_libraries(SomeExecutable -pthread -lboost_thread ${Boost_LIBRARIES} myLib armadillo)
```

**File structure (shortened for brevity):**

```
├── bin
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Common
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── dataContainer.h
│   │   ├── FunctionOne.h
│   │   ├── FunctionTwo.h
│   └── src
│       ├── FunctionOne.cpp
│       └── FunctionTwo.cpp
├── SomeExecutable.cpp
├── myLib
│   ├── example.cpp
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── Config.h
│   │   ├── Helper.h
│   ├── libmyLib.so
```

**UPDATE:**

**myLib/include/Config.h:**

```
Namespace Helper {
[...]
    Level* initLevel(const std::string& jsonLvlPath, bool twiceSpatPts =        false);
[..]
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
kepj@laptop:~/ProjectName$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/SomeExecutable.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++      CMakeFiles/SomeExecutable.dir/SomeExecutable.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SomeExecutable.dir/Common/src/FunctionOne.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SomeExecutable.dir/Common/src/FunctionTwo.cpp.o SomeExecutable  -L/usr/local/lib -rdynamic -pthread -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lmyLib -lsymbolicc++ -lmatio -larmadillo -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib 
CMakeFiles/SomeExecutable.dir/Common/src/FunctionTwo.cpp.o: In function `FunctionTwo::FunctionTwo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, double, unsigned int, bool)':
FunctionTwo.cpp:(.text+0x490): undefined reference to `Helper::initLevel(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/SomeExecutable.dir/build.make:174: recipe for target 'SomeExecutable' failed
make[2]: *** [SomeExecutable] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kepj/ProjectName'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SomeExecutable.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SomeExecutable.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kepj/ProjectName'
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: So in which file is `Helper::initLevel` located?  And what does it look like?

Comment: My guess is there is a `Helper.cpp` that you forgot to include in CMake, can't be conclusive without more data though

Comment: `initLevel` is declared in Config.h, but where is it defined? It seems to be missing from your compiled source, or the definition has a different signature.

Comment: @KarstenKoop It's in libmyLib.so, which is distributed with the source.

Comment: Please share what you see when you run `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: @Cheezmeister I have updated the question with the output.

Comment: @RussellGreene Helper::initLevel should be defined in myLib.so. That's why myLib.so is ditributed with the source.

Comment: Make sure myLib.so is not built by an outdated version of gcc. For more info google *undefined reference __cxx11::basic_string* (no quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is technically still not enough information about this issue to answer this question with certainty, but I am going to share how I would debug this isssue, only knowing what is in the question, explaining each step along the way.

## Make sure you are linking to the correct `myLib.so`

This one is pretty explanatory, and would be my best guess as to the root of this problem.

Relevant compiler flags: `-L/usr/local/lib -lmyLib`

When trying to find the library you specified with the `-l` argument to your compile command, there is a series of steps that the linker takes:
1. It sees if the argument passed to `-l` was an absolute path (entire path to the library, ie starting with `/` on *nix computers or a drive letter on Windows) or just a name. If it is a absolute path, then it knows where it is. In this case, it is just a name, so continue on to step 2.
2. The next place to  look is in the paths specified in `-L` arguments. In this case the only `-L` argument is to `/usr/local/lib` so it looks there. This may or may not be where it is found for this specific case. Look in your filesystem to see if the file `/usr/local/lib/libmyLib.so` exists, and if so make sure that is the version that is most recenpt.
3. Now it searches in [configured linker paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922949/1601448). Use the same steps as in step 2 for each of these paths.

This is my guess because there is no reference to your `myLib` folder in your linker arguments, yet you claim it is in that folder, so I think it is using an out of date `myLib.so`.

## Make sure the `.so` or `.a` file actually has the symbol that is undefined

On linux, you can [list the symbols defined in a `.so` file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34732/1601448). Make sure the symbol that is resolving to undefined is in there.

If they aren't there, here are the possible causes:

1. You aren't using all the C++ source files (`.cpp`) to create your library.
2. The definition and the declaration don't match:

   1. You forgot to enter `namespace Helper` before defining the function
   2. You misspelled the function name
   3. The arguments/return type don't match
   4. For member functions, you forgot to include `MyClass::` before the function name.

## ABI mismatch

(thanks to n.m in the comments for pointing this out)

Because there are multiple implementations (and versions) of the C++ standard library, it is possible that you have an *ABI Mismatch*.

This means that the standard library that `myLib` was compiled with *is not compatable* with the one you are trying to compile your executable with. For example, when you compile `myLib` with libstdc++ on linux, then go to mac and try to compile your executable, where the standard library is libc++ you *will* get errors. Why? The signature for anything, for example `std::string` is not the same. They are different classes entirely, and will cause a signature mismatch while linking.

Comment: You forgot the most probable reason of this error: *C++ ABI mismatch* (if you see __cxx11 something yadda yadda, you can be reasonably sure it's the ABI).

Comment: Yes, let me add that