# linux compilation - conflicting libraries

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

So I am not working on a computer but on an embedded device running ubuntu.

I am trying to compile openCV code but I have the feeling that I am in a deadlock!

This is the error I get:
problem:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.3.2, needed by //usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.2.4
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYlsBYW.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv11setIdentityERKNS_17_InputOutputArrayERKNS_7Scalar_IdEE'
/usr/local/lib//libopencv_core.so.3.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

rename 2.4 libraries:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/usr/lib$ sudo mv libopencv_core.so libopencv_core.soMyOld
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/usr/lib$ sudo mv libopencv_core.so.2.4 libopencv_core.so.2.4MyOld
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/usr/lib$ sudo mv libopencv_core.so.2.4.10 libopencv_core.so.2.4.10MyOld
```

recompile code

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.2.4, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2, needed by //usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmcvWug.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6circleERKNS_17_InputOutputArrayENS_6Point_IiEEiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEEiii'
/usr/local/lib//libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

renaming 3.2 libraries:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/usr/local/lib$ sudo mv libopencv_core.so 
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/usr/local/lib$ sudo mv libopencv_core.so.3.2 libopencv_core.so.3.2MyOld
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/usr/local/lib$ sudo mv libopencv_core.so.3.2.0 libopencv_core.so.3.2.0MyOld
```

recompile

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.3.2, needed by //usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2, needed by //usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cclHSHtB.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6circleERKNS_17_InputOutputArrayENS_6Point_IiEEiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEEiii'
/usr/local/lib//libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What can I do to solve this issue? Uninstalling everything and reinstalling is not an option...

**EDIT:**

I compile with this command:

```
g++ src/personDetection.cpp src/personRecognition.cpp main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -pthread -o main
```

Comment: I guess you are on a tegra board. Maybe you should remove the default installed OpenCV library: `OpenCV4Tegra`.

Comment: @devnglee "maybe"? Why aren't you sure? Btw notice that the errors aren't about opencv version 4 like the one you are referring to and on my board there was no default installed openCV.

Comment: `opencv4tegra` stands for opencv for tegra. Forget about that if your board didn't have that. So you have 2.4 installed   already and tries to install 3.2?

Comment: @devnglee I made some mistake during the installation (long time ago) and ended up installing another version of openCV (don't remember what the issue was and what I ended up doing). Today suddenly, when trying to compile my openCV code I het this error and am unable to compile my code. (I have been able to compile it for many months untill today, I don't understand what happened)

Comment: Maybe library paths given to compiler are messed up. You should tell your compiler to use only one version. It is hard to figure out what exactly went wrong with the informations you've provided.

Comment: @devnglee how should I tell this to my compiler? What extra info do you need?

Comment: You can search the web for yourself but here is a simple example: `g++ -L/usr/lib main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs` this will search for `libopencv_core.so` and `libopencv_imgcodecs.so` from `/usr/lib` and linker will link that library to your code.

Comment: That worked!! Feel free to post it below and I'll accept your answer. What's the difference between -L and -I? Why did that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-L` option is used to specify the *directory path*. Compiler will search this directory with other system standard directories, such as directories in `LIBRARY_PATH`. **But it searches directories specified with -L first**.

`-l` option is used to specify the *name* of the library.

In your case, 2.4 version libraries are in `/usr/lib` and 3.2 version libraries are in `/usr/local/lib`. Your code, probably, is expecting 2.4 version, but your system may be set to search `/usr/local/lib` before searching `/usr/lib` and this may be the cause of your problem.

By specifying `-L/usr/lib` you are telling compiler to search `/usr/lib` first, resulting in using 2.4 version libraries.

---

**UPDATE**

```
$ gcc -m64 -Xlinker --verbose  2>/dev/null | grep SEARCH | sed 's/SEARCH_DIR("=\?\([^"]\+\)"); */\1\n/g'  | grep -vE '^$'
```

Above command will show you the list of default searched directories when linking. (copied the command from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29546339/7724939))

In my machine(Ubuntu 16.04, 64-bit), `/usr/local/lib` appears before `/usr/lib`. This means that a library in `/usr/local/lib` can override libraries in `/usr/lib`. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44406589/7724939))