# Conflict Between Libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, poco-libraries

I know this question has been asked few number of times but after searching for a day I still cannot resolve it. I am trying to use the POCO C++ LIBRARIES and ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS comes with POCO 1.3 installed. I downloaded the latest version of POCO and built and installed it to /home/{username}/poco-1.9.0-all. But when I build my project using eclipse I get the following error:

```
Building target: AuthorizationServer
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/{username}/poco-1.9.0-all/lib -o "AuthorizationServer"  ./src/entity/ResourceOwner.o  ./src/database/MySQL.o  ./main.o   -lPocoFoundation -lPocoData -lPocoMySQL
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libPocoData.so.9, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libPocoMySQL.so, may conflict with libPocoData.so.60
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libPocoFoundation.so.9, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libPocoMySQL.so, may conflict with libPocoFoundation.so.60
Finished building target: AuthorizationServer
```

But following the instructions from [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44393801) I can see that my project has been properly configured and uses -L/home/{username}/poco-1.9.0-all/lib. Can anyone help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.
My eclipse project properties is as follow:

C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Includes->Include paths(-I) contains /home/{username}/poco-1.9.0-all/include

C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->GCC C++ Linker->Libraries->Libraries (-l) contains PocoFoundation, PocoData, PocoMySQL

C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->GCC C++ Linker->Libraries->Library search path(-L) contains /home/{username}/poco-1.9.0-all/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that `-lPocoMySQL` comes from `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libPocoMySQL.so`, not from `/home/{username}/poco-1.9.0-all/lib`.

Make sure that:

- you have built `libPocoMySQL.so`, and
- `/home/{username}/poco-1.9.0-all` is a valid path (it does not look like one).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looking at the library now I understood that PocoMySQL has been renamed to PocoDataMySQL in the latest version of the library. Using -lPocoDataMySQL resolved the issue.