# How do I know the path of libraries used by ld?

Tags: linker, clang, llvm, ld, llvm-clang

Say I'm building and linking my application with clang

```
clang -I/usr/local/include -c -o app.o main.c
clang -L/usr/local/lib -o app app.o -lfoo
```

How do I know where `libfoo.a` or `libfoo.dylib` is located? Is there a verbose mode?

It's possible to search `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` manually, but doing so would be too tedious when you use many libraries.

Comment: You can find solution for Linux here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9929507/829116. See `-Wl,--verbose`

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you want, bu try `ldd app`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the linker is GNU `ld`, pass the [linker option `--trace`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html), e.g.

```
clang -L/usr/local/lib -o app app.o -lfoo -Wl,--trace
```

If the linker is Darwin mach-o `ld`, pass the [linker option `-t`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ld/), e.g.

```
clang -L/usr/local/lib -o app app.o -lfoo -Wl,-t
```

The linker will then report the path of each object file, archive(member) or
dynamic library that it loads.