# The problem with wiringPi library on ODROID-C2 - function not declared in this scope

Tags: c, raspberry-pi3, odroid, wiringpi

I work with ODROID-C2. I have installed the wiringPi library followed the instructions (from page https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-c2/application_note/gpio/wiringpi):

`$ sudo apt install git`

`$ git clone https://github.com/hardkernel/wiringPi`

`$ cd wiringPi`

`$ sudo ./build`

and finaly I get the information "All Done".
However during the instalation among different common warnings (e.g. "`ignoring return value of ...`") I get the following warning (e.g.):
"`implicit declatration of function 'pinMode' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`".
Similar warnings related to the diffrent functions appear many times during library instalation. 
After instalation the usage of the command `gpio readall` allows to get the whole map of pins. Moreover, if I add the library to my program in `C`(`#include <wiringPi.h>`), the program is compiled successfully. However, when I use the command from library (e.g. `wiringPiSetup();`), the compilation fails and the following error appears:
`16: error: 'wiringPiSetup' was not declared in this scope`.
My simple code bellow:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wiringPi.h> 
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    wiringPiSetup();
    while (1)
    {
        printf("*** T E S T ***\n");
        usleep(100000);   
    }

}
```

How can I fix the problem with wiringPi library?

Comment: Did you provide your compiler collection an argument to link `wiringPi`? There is a snippet on the page you linked that does exactly that. It's the first snipper in Odroid-C2 section (look at `-lwiringPi` argument). Also take a look [at gcc's `-l` option](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html)

Comment: I use the following command to compile the file in Geany: `gcc -Wall -c "%f" -lwiringPi`

Comment: What happens when you add `extern          void wiringPiSetup (void);` before `int main`?

Comment: After adding above line a new error appears: `undefined reference to wiringPiSetup`

Comment: Well it means that `wiringPi` library is not available under default path.

Comment: You can check the paths by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29546339/2429333)

Comment: IIRC when you are not providing any `-L` option to the compiler you will get only the libraries that are listed by running `ldconfig --verbose`.

Comment: After running `ldconfig --verbose` I get: `/usr/local/lib:`          `libwiringPi.so  -> libwiringPi.so.2.44` and           `libwiringPiDev.so  -> libwiringPiDev.so.2.44`.

Comment: Could you check if `wiringPiSetup` symbol is in `libwiringPi.so` by running `nm -g /usr/local/lib/libwiringPi.so`?

Comment: After running above commend I've just got list of some "functions" (or someting like that) with I suppose adresses written in hex on the left. I'm not familiar with linux-systems, so is this correct? There is `wiringPiSetup` on this list.

Comment: This is a list of symbols defined in the library. It's a wild guess but try changing options order in build command to `gcc -Wall -lwiringPi -c "%f"`.

Comment: I've tried but still is wrong.

Comment: Is there an alternative in geany to provide libraries to link to the final target? I just realised that '-c' means it is an intermediary object compilation. You need to add this library wiringPi to final linking.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correctly. After compilation,  I can click button Build which runs the following command:'gcc - Wall -o "%e" "%f" -lwiringPi' , but this other action while the error occures during the compilation.

Comment: By the way, you are using `<cstdio>` . It's C++ library. Can this be related? Are you sure you are compiling with gcc and not `g++`? Maybe you should edit your `g++` compilation flags?

Comment: Regarding your understanding correctly, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264256/2429333) to get deeper understanding how the process works.