# Building gperf from source

Tags: configure, autotools

I'm trying to build gperf(Google's profiler) from source. During build process the following error comes up :

```
src/stacktrace_config.h:58:5: error: #error Cannnot calculate stack trace: need either libunwind or frame-pointers (see INSTALL file)
src/stacktrace.cc:109:3: error: #error Cannot calculate stack trace: will need to write for your environment
make: *** [stacktrace.lo] Error 1
```

So it seems i  need `libunwind`.

1) I got the library from savannah's git repo. 
2) Installed it in `/opt/unwind`. 
3) I also added `/opt/unwind/lib/pkgconfig` to my `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.
4) I edited `libunwind.pc` so that both `pkg-config --cflags --libs libunwind` comes up with correct values.
5) I added a `libunwind.conf` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` pointing to `/opt/unwind/lib`.

After all of these i've rerun `./configure` in `gperf` root directory.

The `config.log` reads following :

```
configure:15852: checking libunwind.h usability
configure:15852: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:67:23: fatal error: libunwind.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:15852: result: no
<***snip****>
configure:15852: checking libunwind.h presence
configure:15852: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:34:23: fatal error: libunwind.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<***snip***>
ac_cv_header_libunwind_h=no
```

So it seems It still does not know where `libunwind` is.

Then i tried to set environment variables with CFLAGS and LDFLAGS like following :

```
arif@khost:~/src/gperf$ CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags libunwind` LDFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs libunwind` ./configure
```

Now `config.log` seems more puzzling :

```
configure:15852: checking libunwind.h usability
 configure:15852: gcc -c -I/opt/unwind/include    conftest.c >&5
 configure:15852: $? = 0
 configure:15852: result: yes
 configure:15852: checking libunwind.h presence
 configure:15852: gcc -E  conftest.c
 conftest.c:34:23: fatal error: libunwind.h: No such file or directory
 compilation terminated.
```

It reports first that there is `libunwind.h` but later it cant find it.

`config.log` also has this curious entry :

```
configure:15852: WARNING: libunwind.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected b     y the preprocessor!
configure:15852: WARNING: libunwind.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
```

Also its putting up `ac_cv_header_libunwind_h=yes`

If i do `make` here it stops with the following error:

```
In file included from src/stacktrace.cc:65:0:
src/stacktrace_libunwind-inl.h:46:23: fatal error: libunwind.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [stacktrace.lo] Error 1
```

Answer (score 7):

You need the `libunwind` headers too. Install the `libunwind-devel` package or equivalent.

Comment: `libunwind-dev` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to bwzhou's answer, I tried following the answers in this SO question:

[How to add include and lib paths to configure/make cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561509/how-to-add-include-and-lib-paths-to-configure-make-cycle)

and was able to finally get past the `fatal error: libunwind.h: No such file or directory` error when compiling gperftools with libunwind-1.2.1 compiled beforehand. More specifically, I set CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS using the commands:

```
export CPPFLAGS='-I'$MY_INSTALL_DIR'/include '$CPPFLAGS

export LDFLAGS='-L'$MY_INSTALL_DIR'/lib '$CPPFLAGS
```

prior to executing `./configure --prefix=$MY_INSTALL_DIR`, where $MY_INSTALL_DIR is my personal, non-standard directory in which I have to install software in the HPC cluster I work with due to lacking adequate permissions. After doing this, I was able to successfully execute make; make install. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Try CPPFLAGS instead of CFLAGS when you invoke configure.