# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JMagick in java.library.path

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

Has anyone used JMagick? I imported the jar using maven and got error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JMagick in java.library.path". After lot of research, I found that I should set the path of libJMagick.so file in java.library.path.  http://www.jmagick.org/6.4.0/ only has the sourcecode of jmagick. I tried following the instructions here (https://gist.github.com/kei2100/4688805) to build jmagick. I'm stuck at below line

./configure --with-java-home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current --with-magick-home=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/

It keeps failing with error "configure: error: 'Unable to locate jni.h'" I have jni.h under my java_home/include folder. I tried passing include folder using --with-java-includes argument. But it still keeps failing. Any idea how to move forward?

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13467057/5223047), you have to specify the JDK include paths as compiler flag, e.g.:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" --with-java-home=$JAVA_HOME --with-magick-home=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1/
```

Alternatively you can also create a file named *config.site* and specify the compiler flags there  (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7619133/5223047)).