# __write_overflow declared with attribute error

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm using `memset` and `memcpy` in my linux kernel project.
When I've tried to `make` the project, I got the following error:

> In function ‘memset’,
>       inlined from ‘init_minifw_read_write_module’ at /home/ido/CLionProjects/Firewall/KernelSpace/minfirewall.c:118:13:
>   ./include/linux/string.h:327:3: error: call to ‘__write_overflow’ declared with attribute error: detected write beyond size of object passed as 1st parameter
>      __write_overflow();

I didn't find any workaround for the above error.

Makefile:

```
obj-m += minfirewall.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I'm running kernel version 4.18.0-15-generic.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` feature for compile-time and run-time protection for finding overflows in the common string (e.g. `strcpy`, `strcmp`) and memory (e.g. `memcpy`, `memcmp`) functions. Info is [here](https://outflux.net/blog/archives/2017/09/05/security-things-in-linux-v4-13/) and [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6974f0c4555e285ab217cee58b6e874f776ff409).

You can explicitly turn this feature off by passing `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` (`-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` will work as well) to the compiler.

EDIT:

It looks like you are building a Linux kernel module. Passing a compiler option for kernel module Makefile is a bit [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478859/is-it-possible-to-set-cflags-to-a-linux-kernel-module-makefile).

Add following to your Makefile:

```
CFLAGS_minfirewall.o := -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0
```

Comment: Can I passing it to the make file ?

Comment: Of course. It depends on how Makefile is written. Typically `CFLAGS` is already present in Makefile, so you just need to add `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` to `CFLAGS` variable. Show me your Makefile, and I can tell you how to do this exactly.

Comment: [If Makefile is well written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129391/append-to-gnu-make-variables-via-command-line), it might give you possibility to pass `CFLAGS` via command line: `make CFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`.

Comment: I passed `make CFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` and got "gcc: error: _FORTIFY_SOURCE=0: No such file or directory"

Comment: Then, as I said, try to add `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` to `CFLAGS` within Makefile.

Comment: I've added my make file to the question.Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope this will work for you finally.

Comment: Hi Andrejs, thank you for all the information, but the issue is still persist. I've added the `CFLAGS_minfirewall.o := -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` and then rum `make` and still got the error above. I missed something ?